# How do you find the derivative of an Implicit function?

Tags: derivatives

how do I find the derivative of a function like this one:

$ 2^{x * y^2} + y^3  = 0$

at the point $ x=0 $

I thought that maybe if I put $x=0$ I get $2^0 = 1$ and then $1 + y^3 = 0$

But then how do I get the derivative of $y^3$ ?

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to solve these type of questions.

EDIT: based on your answers I tried to do the following, is this correct?

$  y^3  = -(2^{x * y^2})$

$ ln(y^3) = -ln(2^{x * y^2})$

$ 3*ln(y) = -x*y^2*ln(2)$

Then getting derivatives from both sides:

$ 3 * y'/y = -ln(2)*y^2 - x*ln(2) * 2y*y' $

x=0 =>

$ 3 * y' / y = -ln(2) *y^2 $

$3 * y' = -ln(2) * y^3$

at $x=0$ the function $y^3 = -1$ so therefore 
$y' = ln(2)/3$

I arrived at the same answer, thanks guys! I got + instead of - and I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to differentiate $2^{xy^2}+y^3$ with respect to $x$ and thne to do $x=0$. You will get$$\log(2)(y^2+2xyy')2^{xy^2}+3y^2y'=0.$$Now, putting $x=0$, you get$$\log(2)y^2(0)+3y^2(0)y'(0)=0.$$Since $y(0)=-1$, you deduce from this that $y'(0)=-\frac{\log2}3$.

Comment: Hey, I understood that (y^3)' = 3y^2*y' but how did you find the derivative of 2^(xy^2) ? can I take the ln of both sides and do it like that? What I mean is take ln(y^3) = ln( 2^x*y^3) and then solve it that way, since I know how to get the derivative of the equation of the right in that way

Comment: @MarkFanter I used the fact the the derivative of $2^x$ is $\log(2)2^x$.

Comment: Thanks! I used the natural log on both sides to get a solution in my edit. I got the same answer(with ln instead of log)

Comment: I've done so. Do you know why my answer is different than yours? I got ln2/3 and not -ln2/3 like others have.

Comment: @MarkFanter When you did $x=0$, $y$ should have become $-1$ (that is, $y(0)=-1$).

Answer (score 1):

Take derivation from both sides. Then you have:  $(y^{2}+2xyy^{'})2^{xy^{2}}ln2+3y^{'}y^{2}=0$. Substitute x=0 then $y^{2}ln2+3y^{'}y^{2}=0$. Since $y=-1$ $y^{'}$ will then be $-ln2\over 3$

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate first and substitute later.Take derivative of each term with respect to x assuming y as a function of x.For example derivative of $y^3$ is $3y^2y'$.Solve your equation for $y'$ and substitute values for x and y and you are done.